# Load a javascript/coffeescript file only for one view in Sails.js

Tags: coffeescript, gruntjs, asset-pipeline, sails.js

In my Sailsjs project, I have a `chat.ejs` view with embedded javascript in it:

```
<h2>Welcome <%= username %></h2>
<div id="messages">
</div>
<script>
  // ...
  var socket = io.connect();
  // ...
</script>
```

But since the javascript code uses `io.connect()`, it needs to be written after the `<script src="/js/dependencies/sails.io.js"></script>` generated by the assets pipeline, which is called in my `layout.ejs`, at the end of the body... therefore after my `chat.ejs` code.

Also as all of my server code is written in coffeescript, I was hoping I could do the same on the client side. And it seems the assets pipeline can do just that:

> By default, files in your `assets/js` folder are included here
>   automatically (between SCRIPTS and SCRIPTS END).  Both JavaScript (.js) and
>   CoffeeScript (.coffee) are supported.

Now, what I can do is just cut the javascript out and put its coffeescript version in a `assets/js/chat/chat.coffee` file. This way, the file is included using the assets pipeline, right after the `sails.io.js` file:

```
    <!--SCRIPTS-->
    <script src="/js/dependencies/sails.io.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/chat/chat.js"></script>
    <!--SCRIPTS END-->
  </body>
</html>
```

But now, my problem is that this `chat.js` file is included in my entire app, not just on the chat view! How can I make my asset elegantly view-specific, so that it's only loaded when the user is on the chat view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to overcome this is to use the concept of partials or blocks. For example, if we are using [swig](https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig/), we can use `block`'s to create a base template for our application as such:

BaseLayout.swig

```
<html>
  <body>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}

    <!-- SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="/js/dependencies/sails.io.js"></script>
    <!-- END SCRIPTS -->

    <!-- CUSTOM SCRIPTS -->
    {% block customScripts %}
    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Chat.swig

```
{% extends 'BaseLayout.swig' %}

{% block content %}
  Hello world
{% endblock %}

{% block customScripts %}
  <script src="/js/chat/chat.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

This should be a **reusable** solution for your case and future cases that you may have.

You can probably use something like [ejs-locals](https://github.com/RandomEtc/ejs-locals) to achieve the same thing, but perhaps a better solution is to switch to a better maintained templating engine like jade or swig.

Switching to swig is simple as going to your `config/views.js` and changing engine to `swig`, and then running a `npm install swig` in your project directory.

Comment: Actually, another reason I wanted to use the assets pipeline is because it handles coffeescript files natively (by compiling them and loading them afterwards), and I was hoping I could use it. And I cannot insert coffee files with `src="js/chat/chat.coffee"`... I will add this detail in my question

Comment: There is no way to do what you want, unless you setup a custom `sails-linker` + coffee compile grunt task.

Comment: Are you sure? When I put my coffee file in assets/js it does get compiled into a js file though, without me having to do anything. The problem is just that it gets loaded on every single page.

Comment: read [this](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Assets) for information on how grunt tasks work. There is a task that compiles all your coffeescript and puts it into a specified `dest` location. One thing you can do is to use my solution and just use the relative `dest` location for `src`'ing JS files.

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but it would be pointless as it is the same grunt task that compiles AND inserts the compiled scripts in the layout... so the script would already be loaded without the need of a block, but it would be loaded on every page. One thing I could maybe do is remove the `<!--SCRIPTS-->` tags and insert sails.io.js manually instead. I just hope that grunt does not need those tags to "generate" sails.io.js in some way...

Comment: ... or my coffee scripts for that matter!

Comment: The tags are for `sails-linker` task to function properly. Sails-linker also has `src` and `dest`. Just change them so it doesn't include the other js files. The solution is really simple if you take time to understand how the grunt tasks work and how to customize them to your needs.

Comment: I don't see any `src` or `dest` tags in the kind of the `SCRIPT` ones. Documentation does not mention "dest" anywhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59218/discussion-between-xinzz-and-bravekenny).

Answer (score 1):

Those `<!--SCRIPTS--><!--SCRIPTS END-->` tags are placed right before the closing `</body>` tag by default so that they won't delay any content loading, but depending on what scripts are being added there's no reason why you can't move them to the beginning of the body or even into the `<head>` section of your layout.  You could also remove `sails.io.js` from the pipeline by moving it outside of the **assets/js** folder and/or modifying the **tasks/pipeline.js** file.

The point is, Sails provides script linking as a convenience, but don't be afraid to modify things to fit your needs!

Comment: This would solve the io.connect() problem, but I would still prefer loading my javascript from a file, and if possible a coffeescript file (see my edit). And I'd rather not have this file loaded on every view.

Comment: Is anyone actually loading 'localhost:1337/ja/dependencies/sails.io.js' from an ordinary script tag??? I've tried accessing it from everywhere (/js..., /assets/js..., /public/js..., .tmp/js..., /.tmp/public/js...) and still just 404ing! Please help!

Comment: @Cody if you just downloaded Sails recently, there was a bug for a few days in the `sails new` which caused the normal asset pipeline not to work.  Open up your `.sailsrc` file and if you see `"hooks": {"grunt": false}`, remove it.  The next time you lift your Sails app it should work with your `<script>` src pointing to `/js/dependencies/sails.io.js`.

Comment: @sgress454, YOU. SAVED. MY. LIFE! That was it! Incredible, I'm laughing to myself out loud right now. Thank you so much for your insight, really. I wish the best for you in your endeavors.

Comment: @sgress454, answer my question at `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30929835/sailsjs-requiring-assets-such-as-sails-io-js/30941507#30941507` and I'll accept your answer. Feel free to elaborate (if necessary) for other readers. Thanks again!