# SailsJS: Requiring Assets, Such As, sails.io.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, gruntjs, sails.js

## As the problem is short & sweet, I'll keep the question so.

## CAN'T LOAD ASSETS.

Using Sails.js (`v0.11.n`).

Can't load assets... That's about it...

I'm trying to load `sails.io.js` -- or now even just `assets/alert.js`.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/dependencies/sails.io.js"></script>` **Doesn't work :(**

Even when I switch the `src` to `/alert.js` -- nothing.

I'm pasting this script tag inside of my `/signup` view -- which loads fine -- but I know sure as heck I'm doing something(s) wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was due to an issue with the `sails new` app generator that has been fixed.  The issue was that for any new app, the Grunt hook would be disabled, so that your assets would not be copied automatically into your app's `.tmp/public` folder at lift time.  This is only supposed to happen if the `--no-front-end` option is used with `sails new`, but it was happening all the time.  You can check for this problem by looking in your app's `.sailsrc` file; if you see:

```
"hooks": {
   "grunt": false
}
```

remove it, and your assets will be accessible again.

Answer (score 1):

Grunt is taking care of the asset pipeline for you. If you look in the source for `layout.ejs`, you'll find some tags for your assets. Grunt is automatically looking into the assets folder, and is including them into your layout.

Comment: There are no assets being loaded into my `layout.ejs` doc. Maybe because I initialized my project with `sails generate new app --no-front-end` -- but I still have all my other front end stuff so I don't think it worked. Either way, this doesn't answer my question: 'How to load assets', not 'how does Sails load them'. For any consolation, I want to load them in my Sails app to make sure I can reference them -- then reference them from a decoupled front-end app which lives somewhere else.